# Maven assembly pugin error creating assembly archieve

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a parent project as 'parent'. I have many modules in that. one module which i am concerned about is using maven assembly plugin, call it 'affirm'. now when I remove all other modules from except'affirm', the build goes success but when I build my parent as a whole with all modules along with the module affirm, the build fails in the distribution assembly with the following error:

> The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
>   o  'com.parent.child:*'
>
> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (binaries) on project distribution: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive affirm: You must set at least one file

This is my distribution assembly xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>affirm</id>

<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includes>
            <include>com.parent.child*</include>
        </includes>
        <binaries>
            <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Laos the build works fine when run locally but fails on jenkins when run with all other modules only. I read few other answers related to this, one says to include dependecysets but in that case even my local build fails giving error of unrecognnized tag.

Please excuse me for not giving whole code which is against my company policy. Tell me if something else is required.